# Can I connect Mac Mini (2018) to a lot of external devices via USB, or should I buy a hub with power supply?

Tags: usb, external-disk, mac-mini, hdmi, power

I have a Mac Mini (2018), and want to connect to the following (simultaneously):

- An external portable SSD
- An external portable HDD
- Several mobile phones (1x iPhone and a few Android phones)
- Two external displays (one via HDMI port, one via USB port, and use a USB-to-HDMI converter) (ONLY these displays have their *own* power supply)

The question is, is it OK if I connect them directly to my Mac Mini (possibly with a USB hub *without* an extra power supply)? Will I damage my Mac Mini? If it is damaged because those devices require too much power, will I see any signs or how can I detect that?

Or, should I buy a USB hub *with a power supply*?

Comment: Which of these devices are powered via USB?

Comment: @nohillside All are connected via USB to mac mini

Comment: I understand this. But which of these devices have their own power supply, which rely on power over USB?

Comment: @nohillside Thank you, question edited. Only displays have its own power supply, all others need to get power from USB cable

Comment: How much is "several" mobile phones?

Comment: @At0mic usually 2 phones, but maximum 5 phones